# Is there any way to make programming in Malbolge any easier?

Tags: esoteric-languages, malbolge

[Andrew Cooke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181772) had to create a genetic algorithm to come up with [the first "Hello World"](http://www.acooke.org/malbolge.html) program for Malbolge two years after it was created. Hisashi Iizawa was able to [create a loop version](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-malbolge-995.html) eight years after it was created. Is there an easier way of creating a "Hello World" program? If I wanted to output something else (i.e. "All Your Bases Are Belong To Us"), what would be an easier way of doing it aside from using a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Using [Scheffer's copy program](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge.shtml), failing that, his ideas on a cross-compiler from Brainf**k would probably be easier.

Comment: not long after i published the hello world program someone sent me an email with a better solution they had worked out by hand.  unfortunately i lost their details, but that suggests something is possible...

Comment: +1 wow. Andrew Cooke actually commented on my post! wow. btw did it have something to do about creating a state machine?

Comment: [somebody made a Lisp in malbolge](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/malbolge-lisp). Its very hard to program in it.